# Admob payment address verification "You have less than one month to verify your PIN"

Tags: google-play, admob, payment

my last admob pin was generated on Dec 2, 2016. But it didn't come to my address. I've waited till today March 6,2017 still I didn't receive any letter. Now admob showing me-

> You have less than one month to verify your PIN, otherwise your ad units will stop displaying ads. Visit the Help Center for more information.

My admob is connected to my google play developer console. Is there anything to change there? Should I request for new pin now (It may take more than a month to come I think) ? or should I do something else ?

NB: I am from Bangladesh and I also searched in post office .

Answer (score 0):

I have got my PIN on my address within given time period, keep calm don't worry. Verify your address and request a new PIN.

Address verification with PIN
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2772302?hl=en

Why I haven't received my PIN
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3198646?hl=en

Request a New PIN
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3198657?hl=en